# I'm trying to sum multiple columns into a new sum column using a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn python and have been trying to figure out how to create a sum column of my data. I want to sum all other columns. I create the new column but all sum values are zero. The data can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvY_LfJENU3yvQEvgh8wywcA7z5T). My code is below, thank you for the help:

```
import pandas as pd
#Importing csv file to chinaimport_df datafram
filename=r'C:\Users\Ing PC\Documents\Intro to Data Analysis\Final Project\CHINA_DOLLAR_IMPORTS.csv'
chinaimport_df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Removing all rows that contain only zeros, thresh since since first column is words
chinaimport_df = chinaimport_df.dropna(how='all',axis=0, thresh=2) 

#Convert NANs to zeros
chinaimport_df=chinaimport_df.fillna(0)

#create a list of columns excluding the first column, to make sum func work later

col_list= list(chinaimport_df)
col_list.remove('Commodity')
print(col_list)

#adding column that sums 

chinaimport_df['Total'] = chinaimport_df[col_list].sum(axis=1)




chinaimport_df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Okay, what's desired output?

Comment: I'm trying to find the sum of the columns. Basically the total imports of each commodity for the year until August.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC this should do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CHINA_DOLLAR_IMPORTS.csv')

df['Total'] = df.replace(r',',"", regex=True).iloc[:, 1:].astype(float).sum(axis=1)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank,this could be done by using applymap but your code seems more concise

Comment: @BAKEZQ Yes we can but I think both `replace` and `sum` should be enough to do the work here. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Abhi! I guess part of the problem was the commas which you removed. But what are you doing with .iloc and .astype? Is that just for converting everything to a float? Wasn't the data already set as a float?

Comment: @user2606257 First of all [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is slicing the dataframe by excluding the first column which is `commodity` in our case. Even though we removed the `comma` from the values the datatype of all the values are still`strings` so we have to convert them to integer for the sum function to work. Here [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) converts all the columns to numeric `float` in this case.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the clarification, that makes a lot of sense.